# Inserting text automatically into search_tweets function in r

Tags: r, rtweet

I am trying to use the function search_tweets, but instead of manually inputing the query, I have it in a dataframe. Is there a way were the function can read the text from the dataframe?

Here is my code `Retweeters1 <- search_tweets(Tweet2, n=100)`, were Tweet2 is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
Retweeters1 <- Tweet2 %>% search_tweets(n=100)
```

Comment: I have the tweet in Tweet2, and I want it to be searched using sear_tweets function. Any suggestion?

Comment: But in your original question you have mentioned that search strings are there in a dataframe like `Tweet2 <-as.data.frame(search_string=c("string1","string2","string3"))` and you want to fetch tweets related to these strings. Please edit your question with more accurate detail if I misunderstood it.

Comment: I have the tweet I want to search for in the Tweet2 dataframe. I want a way were I can search_tweet without typing what is in Tweet2 manually.